# Visual studio code docker container error

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, pip, dockerfile

I want to use a docker container with VS code. I added configuration files for Anaconda configuration container and build it. VS Code created a dockerfile:

```
# See here for image contents: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.231.6/containers/python-3-anaconda/.devcontainer/base.Dockerfile

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/anaconda:0-3

# [Choice] Node.js version: none, lts/*, 16, 14, 12, 10
ARG NODE_VERSION="none"
RUN if [ "${NODE_VERSION}" != "none" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} 2>&1"; fi

# Copy environment.yml (if found) to a temp location so we update the environment. Also
# copy "noop.txt" so the COPY instruction does not fail if no environment.yml exists.
COPY environment.yml* .devcontainer/noop.txt /tmp/conda-tmp/
RUN if [ -f "/tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml" ]; then umask 0002 && /opt/conda/bin/conda env update -n base -f /tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml; fi \
    && rm -rf /tmp/conda-tmp

RUN apt-get update

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
# RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
#     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends <your-package-list-here>
```

But when I add command `RUN apt-get` or any another command (for example: RUN pip3 install opencv-python) at the and of this dockerfile then I get an error: "An error occurred setting up the container."

It is very strange problem. This commands are correctly, but I can't to change original dockerfile. After any change in the dockerfile I get this error. What is way to solve this problem? I want to ask for some examples of correct dockerfiles with right pip3 packages installation.

Also I want to ask. Where does VS code keep created docker images?

Comment: When you attempt to build the container and it fails, there should be a prompt to view the creation log. That should give you a bit more context as to why the image build failed.

And regarding where VSCode keeps the images, VSCode is using your local Docker server which is where the resulting images will be stored. You should be able to see all of the built images by running `docker image ls` in your local shell.